# Security updates in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, .net, dnx

Here is coming fresh new ASP.NET 5, where .net platform is specific for application and is independent from the rest of the system.

My question is, what if there will be a security risk like 0-day, where you will be enforced to apply patch to all instances of applications running on vulnerable versions. How to provide upgrades to all application and be confident that you haven't missed anything? Because operating system no longer can help us with it.

Comment: Since asp.net is open source, you gotta follow security related repos on Github and apply/patch them if required.

Answer (score 1):

Servicing is actually part of ASP.NET 5 RC1. In case of a security vulnerability an update can be pushed (or installed by the user). [Here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Servicing) is a Wiki page about servicing (it may be a bit out-of-date) in ASP.NET 5. With the move to .Net CLI servicing is being moved there.